# Unable to parse xml for rich text editor in InfoPath form using PowerAutomate

Tags: sharepoint, xml-parsing, power-automate, infopath

I want to fetch all the text inside below  tag using PowerAutomate expression, How can i achieve that? Right now i am trying with below xpath expression but it is nor returning readable result.

```
xpath(xml(outputs('Compose_3')),'//purpose')



 <purpose>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Action due to regulatory compliance.</div>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> </div>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">These corrective action are required by European Guideline 94/9/EG, 1999/92/EG (ATEX) and their implementation in German law BetrSichV and TRBS.</div>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Based on Risk analysis (Explosion protection </div>
 </purpose>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what you've done is obtained the values within but it's encoded as base64, you can avoid that though.  Therefore, I've got two approaches for you.

### All Text Extract

This is the flow ...

[image: Flow 1]

**Initialize XML**

This is merely your XML in a string variable so I can get the answer you need.

**Initialize Inner Text**

This expression will give you all of the inner text contained within the `purpose` element.

```
xpath(xml(variables('XML')), 'string(//purpose)')
```

This is the result ...

[image: Result 1]

### Array of Texts

This is the more complicated approach but what it does is split out the text strings into an array variable so you're able to control it better if need be.

This is the flow ...

[image: Flow 2]

**Initialize XML**

This is merely your XML in a string variable so I can get the answer you need.

**Initialize Purpose Children**

This is an xml/xpath expression to get an array of all `div` elements within the `purpose` element.

[image: Initialize Purpose Children]

The expression with that step is ...

```
xpath(xml(variables('XML')), '//*[local-name()="div"]')
```

**Initialize Inner Text Array**

This is just a blank array that will be populated within the subsequent `Apply to Each`.

**Apply To Each (Purpose Elements)**

You want to loop through all of the items within the `Purpose Children` array.

[image: Apply To Each]

The only action occurring within there is to append to the `Inner Text Array` variable.

The expression within that step is ...

```
xpath(xml(concat('<xml>', base64ToString(item()?['$content']), '</xml>')), 'string(//*[local-name()="div"])')
```

This is the end result ...

[image: Result 2]

This approach also allows you to concatenate the strings together to produce a more legitimate paragraph of text.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable comment. First approach worked perfectly fine for me which will solve the purpose. However 2nd approach  `xpath(xml(variables('XML')), '//*[local-name()="div"]')`      was returning the result in below format                                                                      
                                                                                                                                
`[{"$content-type":"application/xml;charset=utf-8","$content":"PHB1cnBvc2U+DQogIDx4aHRtbDpkaXYgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzM=="}]`

Comment: Having similar issue can you help https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305125/get-value-from-http-response-xml-and-pass-it-as-a-field-in-next-http-request-fie

Comment: So the answer provided to you didn’t help?